# How to dynamically update content based on language choices in Shiny App without using renderUI in server

Tags: r, shiny, internationalization, shiny.i18n

I am working on a Shiny app that includes internationalization (i18n) support using the [shiny.i18n](https://github.com/Appsilon/shiny.i18n) package. I have a translator object that handles translations based on the selected language. I want to dynamically update texts in the UI without using the renderUI function in the server. I need to reach the function from ui.

Here's a simplified version of my code:

```
`library(shiny)
library(shiny.i18n)

translator <- Translator$new(translation_json_path = "translation.json")


  i18n <- reactive({
    selected <- input$selected_language
    if (length(selected) > 0 && selected %in% translator$get_languages()) {
      translator$set_translation_language(selected)
    }
    translator
  })


ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel (
      selectInput("selected_language", 
                  translator$t("Change Language"),
                  choices = translator$get_languages(),
                  selected = input$selected_language)
    ),

    mainPanel(p(translator$t("Hello")))
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {

}

shinyApp(ui, server)`
```

Here is translator.json:
`{ "cultural_date_format": "%d-%m-%Y", "languages": ["en", "tr"], "translation": [ {"en": "Hello", "tr": "Merhaba"}, {"en": "Change Language", "tr": "Dil Değiştir"} ] }`

I've tried using observeEvent and renderUI, but the approach is not suitable for the project. Is there an alternative way to achieve dynamic translation updates in the mainPanel without using renderUI? I appreciate any insights or suggestions you can provide.

Comment: Perhaps you can use `conditionalPanel()` in the `ui`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can manage add translations in the UI.
This [repo](https://github.com/Appsilon/shiny.i18n/tree/main/examples/live_language_change) may be helpful for this purpose.

```
library(shiny)
library(shiny.i18n)

i18n <- Translator$new(translation_json_path = "translation.json")
i18n$set_translation_language("English") # here you select the default translation to display


ui <- fluidPage(
  shiny.i18n::usei18n(i18n),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel (
      selectInput("selected_language", 
                  i18n$t("Change Language"),
                  choices = i18n$get_languages(),
                  selected = i18n$get_key_translation())
    ),
    
    mainPanel(
      p(i18n$t("Hello")),
      htmlOutput("html_output")
    )
  )
)


server <- function(input, output) {
  observeEvent(input$selected_language, {
    shiny.i18n::update_lang(input$selected_language)
  })
  
  
  output$html_output <- renderText({
    i18n$set_translation_language(input$selected_language)
    # paste0(i18n$t("Hello"))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```